# How to get the length of an entered argument with GNU get opt

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying to 'prettify' some code that makes a log file and in the log file I want to print the name of the input files and what settings were used in a nicely formatted #-box. I need to be able to get the length of an entered argument which has to be stored by the GNU getopt somewhere for it's internal malloc, at least I assume that's how they did it..

Does anyone know how to get that value? I could then use some simple calculus to see howmuch whitespace that I need to add after the last letter of text in my comment box ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where your code stores the value, it is available in the

```
extern const char *optarg;
```

variable, and you can simply use `strlen()` to compute the length of the string.

Comment: That makes sense, I was staring at the struct they defined and couldn't figure it out o.O. Adding the contents of the struct in case someone else reads this and has a similair question: *name, has_arg, *flag and val (none contain argument length obviously).